# In tensorflow, I get the error info "try: return fn(*args) except errors.OpError as e:"

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
w1= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 3], stddev=1, seed=1))
w2= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 1], stddev=1, seed=1))
```

---

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(3, 2), name="input")
a = tf.matmul(x, w1)
y = tf.matmul(a, w2)
sess = tf.Session()
##使用tf.global_variables_initializer()来初始化所有的变量
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()  
sess.run(init_op)
print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: [[0.7,0.9],[0.1,0.4],[0.5,0.8]]}))
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
print (tf.__version__)
```

returns 1.2.1

and I use python 3.5.3 in anaconda

I run my code in jupyter notebook. When run the cell(second one)，I come across a error. The detailed information is shown in the picture.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed my problem.
Probably my tensorflow version or python version is a little bit old. So I cannot use tf.global_variables_initializer(), but tf.initialize_all_variables(). And if one of these two doesn't work, you guys may try the other one!!